# Java Thread.sleep(delay) not working

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

Hi I'm trying to execute task every `X` seconds and I have problem with it:

```
Thread joinThread = new Thread(() -> {
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        Player player = new Player(user, RandomUtils.randomString(10), host, p, event.getSession());
        player.join();
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(delay);
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        ignored.printStackTrace();
    }
});

joinThread.start();
```

It looks like `Thread.sleep(delay)` is ignored because my thread is executing itself every ms instead of delay

Here's my `join` method:

```
public void join(){
    GameProfile profile = session.getFlag("profile");
    Client c = new Client(host, port, new MinecraftProtocol(name), new TcpSessionFactory(proxy));
    c.getSession().addListener(new SessionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void packetReceived(PacketReceivedEvent event) {
            if (event.getPacket() instanceof ServerJoinGamePacket) {
                user.setBotAmount(u.getBotAmount()+1);
                user.addBot(event.getSession());
                System.out.println("Player bot joined");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void disconnected(final DisconnectedEvent event) {
            if(event.getCause() != null) event.getCause().printStackTrace();
            user.setBotAmount(u.getBotAmount() -1);
        }
    });
    c.getSession().connect();
}
```

If remove `player.join();`, it's working like a charm.
Any advice? I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: *my thread is executing itself every ms* - This is impossible. You didn't schedule the thread, it will run just once.

Comment: What is the value of `delay`?  What is `Player`?  You have a `join` method; does it subclass `Thread`?

Comment: Are you sure that this code snippet isn't inside some loop?

Comment: No, please don't link to code.  What you need to do get help here on SO is to edit your question to add more details in the question itself -- i.e. create a [mcve] -- or no one will be have enough information to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the body of a thread (the body of the `run` method) executes once.

You are trying to make a delay for each player. Then you need to put the `Thread.sleep(delay)` inside the loop after the `player.join()`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    Player player = ...;
    player.join();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(delay);
    } catch (InterruptedException reallyIgnored) {}
}
```

Otherwise, you are going to make a delay **after** all the players are already processed which makes no sense.

Make sure that the `delay` variable is set correctly. The `Thread.sleep` takes time in milliseconds. To feel the difference, the value is supposed to be `>1000`.